# Sitecore Glass Mapper Link Field cannot be edit by Page Editor Mode

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, asp.net-mvc-5.2, glass-mapper

Hi I'm currently using Sitecore 8.1 update 1 with MVC5.2.3 and Glass Mapper. I'm having some issues with the Glass Mapper link field. I have created a template which is derived from Standard Rendering Parameters template in which I have used Sitecore `General Link` field. Also I have created Model for that:

My model:

```cs
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{912B074D-F8BA-4AA7-9276-016515A1ACE8}")]
public class RelatedArticleParams
{
     [SitecoreId]
     public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

     public virtual string HeaderText { get; set; }

     [SitecoreField(FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.GeneralLink)]
     public Link Link { get; set; }
}
```

My View:

```
@{
    var parameters = GetRenderingParameters<RelatedArticleParams>();
}
<a href="@parameters.Link.Url" class="linkdark">@parameters.Text</a>
```

Everything is fine if I add the link from presentation details at Sitecore backend. But when I click on this component at Sitecore Page Experience Editor and insert link to Rendering Parameters, then it will give An error occurred red line indication at top of the page. I cant insert link from Page Editor mode.

Please help me in this issue whether it is Glass Mapper bug or I am making any mistake ??

Thanks.
Will appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Are there any errors in your log files? Check the browser console and the AJAX/xhr calls that are made and check the messages of the response to tell  us what error is being thrown.

Comment: Your `RelatedArticleParams` class has a `HeaderText` property, but your view uses `@parameters.Text`.  Was this just a typo when creating the  SO question or is that the real code?

Comment: Use the BeginRenderLink or Editable.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to do it in code.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public HtmlString MyLink { get; set; }
}
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IGlassHtml _glassHtmlHelper;
    public void MyController()
    {
        _glassHtmlHelper = new GlassHtml(new SitecoreContext());
    }
    public ViewResult MyControllerAction()
    {
        var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        //Get your item
        viewModel.MyLink = new HtmlString(_glassHtmlHelper.RenderLink<RelatedArticleParams>(contentItem, x => x.Link, isEditable: true));
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Then, in your markup, all you have to do is:

```
@model MyViewModel
<div>
    @Model.MyLink
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use
@Editable(Property name of glass mapper) //using the Model property.

[Reference](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial22)

Answer (score 2):

use

@RenderLink(x => x.Link)

or

```
@using (BeginRenderLink(x => x.GeneralLink, isEditable: true))
{
    @RenderImage(x => x.Image)
}
```

http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial22